# Modal is not a function

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, angular6

I am getting `$(...).modal is not a function` error while try to open 
modal in `OnInit` function in my TS file.

Firstly I loaded Jquery.min.js in my index.html and secondly loaded 
bootstrap.min.js

I am using Float label in my bootstrap app and it's working with jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('[data-toggle="floatLabel"]')
     .attr('data-value', $(this).val())
     .on('keyup change', function() {
       $(this).attr('data-value', $(this).val());
     });
  $('#exampleModal').modal('show'); 
 });
```

Comment: please send  error and detail

Comment: what 's version bootstrap and jquery

Comment: is this a typescript compile error or does this error actually show in browser?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=modal+is+not+a+function

Comment: Error shows in browser i am using Bootstrap 4.1.3 and jQuery 2.2.4

Answer (score 0):

maybe u sorted library wrongly

u need to push jquery library

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

before boostrap

`<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`